# Form not submitting when file for upload is missing

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, submit, form-submit

I'm having issues when I try to submit a form with a file, when the file for upload has changed after it has been selected but before submitting the form (for example renaming of the file). The form simply does not submit. This is my example code:

```
<form action="test.htm" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="test">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').submit(function() {
        console.log("IT WORKS!");
        return true;
    });
});
</script>
```

**UPDATE**

Even more simplified, using this code:

```
<form action="upload.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Try do this: 1) Select a file from your system 2) Rename the file on your system 3) Submit the form.

Nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering why the `console.log` is not showing, it is because the form is already being submitted.

Just add a `event.preventDefault` to make sure your code runs.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#test').submit(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("IT WORKS!");
        return true;
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/aqanor/1/edit)

**UPDATE**

Your action path is to a `.htm` file. You will need a server-side language to process the `POST`.

Comment: It's not the console.log that fails in my case, but actually the form submit. I've tried with your code and it fails as well (on Chrome at least). Try to do this:
1) Add a file
2) Rename the file on the system
3) Submit the form.
Then nothing happens.

Comment: Removing the Javascript completely is also an OK solution, however, it fails as well. I added the Javascript to see if I could catch any error.

Comment: I've just tested in IE8 and it also fails in that browser.

Comment: Just noticed your action is a `.htm` file!

Comment: Yes, this is just for testing purposes. In the real code it's .asp. I just wanted to simplify the code for finding the error.

Comment: @user1770444 : Just submit the form, and check the logs to see if any errors are there

Comment: There are no entries in the log. The form is simply not submitting. This is not only on my computer as the DEMO you've posted fails as well.

Comment: The form does submit. I just don't have permissions to upload. [Check here](http://jsbin.com/oqizal/1/edit)

Comment: @user1770444 : Ignore the JavaScript, it is useless. Before these comments, it was assumed that you were wondering why the `console.log` was not working, thus had written the JavaScript

Comment: I've updated my description of the problem, however, I never mentioned that it was the console.log that wasn't working. I've only mentioned that the form wasn't submitting. The console.log have always been outputtet, so no errors there.

Answer (score 0):

your javascsript function is of no use.. since

```
<input type="submit"..
```

will already submit the form before it is called

one way is to use `preventDefault()` in your function..

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#test').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("IT WORKS!");
    return true;
 });
});
```

OR make your input as button

```
<button id="submit">Submit</button>

$('#submit').click(function(){
$('#test').submit(function() {
   console.log("IT WORKS!");
   return true;
 });
});
```

Comment: Without the Javascript it still fails. See my comments to Pranav.